# Not receiving notification of the next user

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I have made a chat app in firebase and users are being notified when a new message comes by the below codes.

```
private void sendNotification(String title, String message, String receiver, String receiverUid, String firebaseToken) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChatActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("name",title);
    intent.putExtra(Const.ARG_RECEIVER, receiver);
    intent.putExtra(Const.ARG_RECEIVER_UID, receiverUid);
    intent.putExtra(Const.ARG_FIREBASE_TOKEN, firebaseToken);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    char[] ch = firebaseToken.substring(0,3).toCharArray();
    String a = "";
    for (char aCh : ch) {
        a = a + Integer.toHexString(aCh);
    }
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, Integer.parseInt(a), intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

 //   Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_noti)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
       //     .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(Integer.parseInt(a), notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

I want to receive different notification when a different user sends a message but for the same user, the notification should be updated. I tried to set unique id by taking the Unicode of first 3 letters of Firebase token of the user but then also it is showing only one notification. If I chat with 2 people the user with whom I have started chat first shows notification but not the second one.
Please have a look and help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just change `FLAG_ONE_SHOT` to `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`.

[FLAG_ONE_SHOT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_ONE_SHOT) :
Flag indicating that this PendingIntent can be used only once.

[FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT) :
Flag indicating that if the described PendingIntent already exists, then keep it but replace its extra data with what is in this new Intent.

Comment: I used that.But it did not show any change. I am trying again and will inform here